# Google Map JS API 3D Navigation Feature

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mapbox, google-earth

Is there any API I can use to implement 3D navigation as shown here in [Mapbox implementation](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-gl-js-0-8-1/)?

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXoJLyN356E) shows how google earth can be integrated with Google map, unfortunately, Google Earth has been deprecated as noted [here](https://developers.google.com/earth/) plus this API requires Google Earth plugin to be installed on the client browser.

[image]

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

Useful live production example can be found at the following link: http://themeforest.net/item/directory-portal-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/3840053 I'd suggest checking the console.